# NodeJS - How to retrieve original data from a Buffer after use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, buffer, cryptojs

I am working with `crypto` library to send a POST request to update some data and for some reason I get as if I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myBufferData))`  to a `Buffer` data. I want to recover the original data.

How you can replicate my situation:

```
var buf = Buffer.from('abc');
var parsedBuf = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buf)); -> I faced with this result at some point.

buf.toString() -> Give the expected result ('abc').
parsedBuf.toString() -> Doesn't retrieve original data ('[object Object]').
```

How can I retrieve the original data from `parsedBuf`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Use `Buffer(parsedBuf).toString()` instead of `parsedBuf.toString()` to retrieve original data.

---

### Explanation

Checking the [Buffer docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), I found out that its `toString` method is not Javascript's built-in. You can simply check it's source wherever you want by calling `buf.[method].toString()`. In this case:

- `buf.toString.toString()`
- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buf)).toString.toString()`

So it revealed me somehow their source code:

```js
// Buffer's toString method
function () {
  let result;
  if (arguments.length === 0) {
    result = this.utf8Slice(0, this.length);
  } else {
    result = slowToString.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  if (result === undefined)
    throw new Error('"toString()" failed');
  return result;
}

// Javascript's built-in
function toString() { [native code] } // I haven't sought to find it out
```

It turns out that whenever you do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buf))` you are actually transforming your Buffer into a Javascript object. For example:

> `{ type: 'Buffer', data: [ 61, 62, 63] }`.

So another `toString()` on it will run **native** JS function (not Buffer's) which returns by default `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thank you @testing_22. Also I found that Buffer.from() gives the expected result.